# Mapping and joining a python list

Tags: python

I'd like to wrap each string in a variable-length list in curly-braces, and join them with a comma. I've currently got this:

```
myList   = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
myString = ','.join( map( lambda s: "{{{0}}}".format(s), myList ) )
print myString
# {foo},{bar},{baz}
```

Python should never be that ugly! Is there a tidier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also give the following a go.  It feels a bit more natural to me.

```
",".join(["{" + e + "}" for e in myList])
```

or as xbello has suggested,

```
",".join(["{%s}" % e for e in myList])
```

Comment: ",".join(["{%s}" % x for x in myList])

Comment: I like the 2nd one. For some reason I like to avoid string concatenation whenever possible..

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
>>> '{' + '},{'.join(myList) + '}'
'{foo},{bar},{baz}'
```

Comment: Clever! I like that way more than mine, but it still takes a little looking at to understand what it does..

Comment: @ajwood Yes, that's true; a clarifying comment would help.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like what you started with. You can shorten the string formatting a little bit though:

```
In [2]: ','.join(map(lambda s:'{%s}'%s, myList))
Out[2]: '{foo},{bar},{baz}'
```

Or (I think slightly less readable)

```
In [3]: ('{%s},' * len(myList))[:-1] % tuple(myList)
Out[3]: '{foo},{bar},{baz}'
```

Comment: Using a lambda with `map` is complete overkill in this case; a simple generator or list comprehension would be preferable. I think both of these solutions overcomplicate what should be a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat off the wall approach:

```
>>> myList   = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
>>> re.sub("'(.*?)'", r"{\1}",repr(myList))[1:-1]
'{foo}, {bar}, {baz}'
```